# WebClient OpenRead doesn't download full file

Tags: c#, stream, webclient

I'm trying to download file via stream with `OpenRead` method of `WebClient` as below.

```
            using (var client = new WebClient()))
            {
                var responseStream = client.OpenRead(new Uri({url}));

                if (responseStream == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Response stream is null");
                }

                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return memoryStream;
            }
```

The problem I keep getting random file sizes. Usually file size is above 50MB but the file I get on the machine is between 10MB-14MB.

When I access to `url` directly from a browser or debug locally I get the full data.

The reason I'm using the OpenRead is other urls I'm using can be very big in size and the issue I'm having seems to be just for this particular url so far.

Comment: @Adrian, I used to have it, due to different urls I get have different sizes, streaming was better option. The issue is with this url I believe.

Comment: `The issue is with this url I believe` So how do you expect us to help you without knowing that url?